# How can I add how much I spent in each category this month?

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

Im trying to track all of my expenses for this month. Im using Google Sheets and just as a small project I want to make it as automated as possible. Eventually I would want to just input the cost and category, and at the end of the month see how much I spent in each category.

So far I have been able to make a dropdown list of possible categories, but now I'm trying to add up how much I spent in each category.

I want to do this by searching for a specific string in the "category" column, and have it make a list containing each row where that string was found. Then in the column where I input the price of the things I bought, go through each element in the list and return the sum of all the cells.

I tried looking at the google sheets help pages for useful functions, but I couldnt find anything.

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: you could use a sumif function. see : https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en

Comment: @player0 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NGa1fq45_fVlE_Rw4S9U4jsL3E5epLX9D80en5AUfQ0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Jeremy But what criteria would I use? I think if I could make the criteria match a string in the corresponding column then it would work. For example, the range would be D2:D (thats the column with categories), and if the 'Fast Food' string is found then add the corresponding rows value in column B (the cost column). How would I make those two work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(Spendings!B2:D, "select D,sum(B) where D is not null group by D label sum(B)''")
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

I got it, thanks to @Jeremy.

Here is what I did in case anyone else finds this:

The SUMIF function takes in where to look, what to look for, and what to add. If that thing is found then it sums the values. The third parameter specifies what to add if the "where to look" parameter is not the values of what I want to add.

So in my example, I did =SUMIF(Spendings!D2:D, "Fast Food", Spendings!B2:B). The D column is where my categories are, and the B column is where the prices are. Every place where the string "Fast Food" is found in column D, it will take the corresponding rows in column B and add them all together.